# What is wrong into this flow?

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript

In my project I can't find what it's wrong.

**The final goal is to change the ShowInList boolean value into the CompanyActivity entity each time i use an API call.**

Project:
*Backend* = C# and SQL.
*Frontend* = Angular 17.

Let's go step by step.

**BACKEND PART:**
This is the API call:

```
[HttpPost, Route("/api/[controller]/ChangeShowInListStatus/")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ChangeShowInListStatus([FromBody]CompanyActivity companyActivity, int FK_Company, int FK_Activity, DateTime InsertDate)
    {
        //List<CompanyActivity> companyActivities = _activityService.GetActivitiesByCompany(companyActivityId);

        //List<ActivityDTO> dto = _autoMappingService.CurrentMapper.Map<List<ActivityDTO>>(companyActivities);
        //var companyActivity = _activityService.GetActivitiesByCompany(companyActivityId);

        _companyActivityService.UpdateCompanyActivity(companyActivity, FK_Company, FK_Activity, InsertDate);

        return Ok();
    }
```

This is the UpdateCompanyActivity inside the ChangeShowInList:

```
public void UpdateCompanyActivity(CompanyActivity companyActivity, int FK_Company, int FK_Activity, DateTime InsertDate)
    {


        GetBy(a => a.FK_Activity == FK_Activity && a.FK_Company == FK_Company && a.InsertDate == InsertDate).FirstOrDefault();
        
        companyActivity.ShowInList = !companyActivity.ShowInList;

        UpdateEntityProperties(companyActivity, true, new string[] { "ShowInList" });
    }
```

This is the UpdateEntityProperties inside UpdateCompanyActivity:

```
public virtual int UpdateEntityProperties(TEntity entity, bool saveChanges, params string[] propertiesToUpdate)
    {
        UpdateValidation(entity, propertiesToUpdate);
        _repository.UpdateEntityProperties(entity, propertiesToUpdate);
        if (saveChanges)
        {
            _uow.SaveChanges();
        }

        return entity.ID;
    }
```

This is the CompanyActivityDTO:

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace H4Pro.Web.Mappings.ModelsDTO.Productivity
{
    public class CompanyActivityDTO
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int FK_Company { get; set; }
        public int FK_Activity { get; set; }
        public DateTime InsertDate { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**FRONTEND PART**
This is the clicked function:

```
changeShowInListStatus(FK_Company: number, FK_Activity: number) {
this.getActivitiesByCompany();
this.FK_Company = this.currentUser.FK_Company;
this.FK_Activity = this.activity.ID;

this.companyActivityService.changeShowInListStatus(FK_Company, FK_Activity).subscribe(() => {});
```

}

And this is the call into companyActivity.service.ts:

```
changeShowInListStatus(FK_Company: number, FK_Activity: number) {
return this.http.get<ActivityDTO>(
  environment.apiFullUrl + "/Activity/ChangeShowInListStatus/" + FK_Company + "/" + FK_Activity
);
```

}

When i try to click the function the two values (FK_Company, FK_Activity) are always undefined.
I don't get what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: When the problem is undefined "FK_Company, FK_Activity" parameters why don't you show us how they are filled or you thought you have filled them? Most of the server code you show is about what you could do when the client would have send those to the server so pretty much unrelated to the problem? So is currentUser filled with the correct expected data. Is activity filled with the correct expected data?